# Flutter Android deep link is not launching the app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-hosting

I have implemented the deep linking feature for my Flutter app following the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking). However, on Android, when I open the deep link on the browser, it does not launch the app.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" /> -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="app.name.com" />

            </intent-filter>
```

this is my domain/.well-known/assetlinks.json file

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.company.app",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [      "DB:34:11:E3.....
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am hosting this file on Firebase Hosting and this is my firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "appAssociation": "NONE",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
        "destination": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association"
      },
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "destination": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

when i used the command to test how the app handles the deep link, it worked as expected

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \ 
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "https://app.name.com"' \
    com.company.app
```

On IOS, it works fine (I get an option to open the app at the top) but it does not work as expected on Android. So what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you added sha256_cert_fingerprints for release on /.well-known/assetlinks.json file?

Comment: yes it is from Google Play console

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue (except I'm hosting on my own server (nginx + laravel). So Ali, if you find the solution, please post it. I've tried everything I can think of and followed advice from the docs and here and elsewhere, but nothing seems to help.